# Django-, display and filter particular fields from a foreign key in a model form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am using a model form, and the field is a foreign key, to another the model, the foreign key model contains a choice field(status) which i want filter based on user group,such that if a user belongs to a group, for example if the user in a group DEVELOPER, the status choices available will be 'Weekly Task' and 'Daily Task'

**models.py**

```
 class ScrumyGoals(models.Model):
     user_name=models.ForeignKey('ScrumyUser', on_delete= models.CASCADE, null= True)
     status_id = models.ForeignKey('GoalStatus', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
     goal_type = models.CharField(choices=GOAL_TYPE, max_length=64, default='DT')
     def __str__(self):
         return '{},{}'.format(self.user_name,self.status_id)

class GoalStatus(models.Model):

    GOALS_TYPE= (('DT','Daily Task'),
        ('WT','Weekly Task'),
        ('V','Verified'),
        ('D','Done'),
)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True) 
    task_id=models.IntegerField(default=1,null=False)
    description =models.CharField(max_length=254)
    verified_by=models.ForeignKey('ScrumyUser', on_delete= models.CASCADE, null=True)
    status=models.CharField(choices=GOALS_TYPE, max_length=2, default='DT')
```

**forms.py**

```
class ChangeTaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ScrumyGoals
        fields = ['status_id']
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    super(ChangeTaskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if user.groups.filter(name ='DEVELOPER').exists():
        self.fields['status'].choices = (('WT','Weekly Task'), ('DT','Daily Task'),)
```

**views.py**

```
    def changetask(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ChangeTaskForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/')
        else:
           form = ChangeTaskForm(user=request.user)
        return render(request, 'oderascrumy/changetask.html', {'form': form})
```

The form only currently shows the status_id , it doesn't show the choices (ie "status")

so in essence what i want is this  if the logged in user is in  group say "DEVELOPER", The user can only change the goal (ie "status_id") choice (ie "status") from weekly task to daily task and the form is saved

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you remove the `if` from forms.py, i.e. are you positive the Group with name 'DEVELOPER' exists, and that the user you're testing with is actually in that group?

An alternative might be to always include `status` in `fields`, then just conditionally show that field in the template with `if user.groups in ['DEVELOPER']`.

Comment: yes, the user belong to the group, how would i include `status` as a field, because it is a field of `goal status` and not `scrumy goals`,  _`status id` is a field in **scrumy goal(fk to goal status)**_, is it possible to display all the fields of `status_id` so that i can work with the status field

Comment: First, as a matter of convention, the `status_id` field should be renamed to `status` - calling it `status_id` is kind of weird in Django (though internally, the db field will still get called `status_id` but that's transparent from the Django side. Secondly,  classes should always be named for the singular, so the ScrummyGoals class should be renamed ScrummyGoal. Third, `status` *is* a field on that class - I'm not sure why you're saying that it is not.

Comment: Thank you for the tips 

**status** is a field in GoalStatus, not ScrumyGoals
Status_id is a field in ScrumyGoals which is a foreign key to GoalStatus, in the change task form , where I call status_id as a field , , when the form is rendered only the title field in GoalStatus is rendered,
My question is there a way to to display the status field(from GoalStatus) in the Form, using the status_id as field?
Thank you